# Image not labeling correctly: how to return only one connected component?

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, labeling

I want to pre-process the image

[image: raw image]

so that only the inner rectangular segment is kept (i.e. remove the surrounding background). But I'm not getting the correct result, which was shown as

[image: cropped image].

for me.

The code is quite simple:

```
def labelim(img):
    #labeling image
    gray = rgb2gray(img) #translate rgb to gray
    val = filters.threshold_local(gray,5)
    mask = gray > val
    clean_border = segmentation.clear_border(mask)
    labeled = label(clean_border)
    signle_labeled = np.where(labeled == 0,labeled, 1)#ensure all assigned label return as 1.
    return single_labeled
def crop_img(img, labeled):    
    cropped_images = []
    pad = 20
    for region in regionprops(labeled):
        if region.area < 2000:
            continue
        minr,minc,maxr,maxc = region.bbox
        cropped_images.append(gray[minr-pad:maxr+pad, minc-pad:maxc+pad])
    for c, cropped_image in enumerate(cropped_images):
        cropim = cropped_image
    return cropim

labeled = labelim(img)
cropped_image = crop_img(img, labeled)
```

The testing code works for another one of my images, but not working for most of them. Thanks for any help/suggestion.

Comment: I have removed the excess part. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: it seems you are starting at 0,0 so either minc/minr are zero (or less than pad) .

Comment: ps. your cropim loop at the end doesn't really make sense

Comment: Can you elaborate? I printed out [minr,minc] as [119L, 128L]. And it did work for another similar image.

Comment: It looks very much like you just took the rect 0,0->200,200 from the original image which would make sense if the minr/c was wrong

Comment: `cropim` is overwritten within the loop. You thus only return the last of the cropped regions.

Comment: I know, in this particular case only one component was labeled, so it does not affect the result here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

one little bug here:

```
cropped_images.append(gray[minr-pad:maxr+pad, minc-pad:maxc+pad])
```

should be:

```
cropped_images.append(img[minr-pad:maxr+pad, minc-pad:maxc+pad])
```